# How to output .html to the root of the dist folder when building a project?

Tags: vite, rollup, rollupjs

When developing, html files are in the “pages” folder, how to move them to the dist/ root when building

```
rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        ...Object.fromEntries(
          glob.sync(resolve(root, 'pages', '*.html')).map((filepath) => {
            const { base, name } = parse(filepath);
            return [name, resolve(root, 'pages', base)];
          })
        ),
        main: resolve(root, 'index.html'),
      },
      output: {
        assetFileNames: ({ name }) => {
          let directory = '';
          if (/\.woff2?/.test(name)) {
            directory = 'fonts';
          }

          directory += directory ? '/' : '';
          return `assets/${directory}[name][extname]`;
        },
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
        chunkFileNames: 'assets/[name].js',
      },
    },
```

[image]